# How to use multiple custom plugin in AEM RTE?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have installed the color picker package provided [here](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2017/06/aem-63-touch-ui-rte-rich-text-editor-color-picker-plugin-inplace-dialog-edit.html)!

Also I have developed another plugin based on this for different functionality but I am not able to use both at same time. Individually both are working fine. One overrides other if they both installed.

Any way or link will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by integrating files in one.